# How can I make CoffeeScript closures aware of non-local variables?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, closures

This is a CoffeeScript fragment using express and async.  How can I make the final callback function aware of the value of template?

```
app.get '/', (req, res) -> template = 'main'
async.parallel([
  (callback) ->
    db.collection1.find(
      {},
      (err, data) ->
      if !err && data  
        callback null, data
      else
        callback null, null
    ),
  (callback) ->
    db.collection2.find(
      {},
      (err, data) ->
      if !err && data  
        callback null, data
      else
        callback null, null
    )
], (err, results) ->
  console.log template
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your `async` block within the `app.get` callback (below `template = 'main'`). Like so:

```
app.get '/', (req, res) -> 
  template = 'main'
  async.parallel([
    (callback) ->
      db.collection1.find(
        {},
        (err, data) ->
        if !err && data  
          callback null, data
        else
          callback null, null
      ),
    (callback) ->
      db.collection2.find(
        {},
        (err, data) ->
        if !err && data  
          callback null, data
        else
          callback null, null
      )
  ], (err, results) ->
    console.log template
  )
```

Comment: That's how it was written.  The formatting didn't go through properly even though I tried to fix it.  My problem turned out to be something different.  Ah, late night programming!